# Using fetch() to get JSON from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, fetch-api

I have the following data.php file:

```
$command = $_REQUEST["command"];
$APIKey = "*******************";

if(!isset ($_REQUEST["command"]))
{
    echo "You didn't provide a valid API command";
}
else
{
  switch($command)
  {
    case "get_token" :
      $dataArr = array("token" => "Bearer " . $APIKey);
      echo json_encode($dataArr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      break;
    default:
      echo "Incorrect API command";
      break;
   }
}
```

Which mean that I have to provide a specific command in the request in order to get the data. It works fine if I use jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method:

```
$.getJSON(
  'php/data.php',
  {
    command: "get_token"
  }, (result) => {
    this.myToken = result.token;
  });
```

However I want to try and use the `fetch()` method. So I tried this:

```
fetch('php/data.php', {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "cors",
  cache: "no-cache",
  credentials: "same-origin",
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
  body: JSON.stringify({command: "get_token"}),

}).then(result => {
  console.log('fetch', result);
  this.myToken = result.token;
})
```

In this case I'm getting this error message: `Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body`.

I tried to use it with POST method, tried with just the body key... Nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Tried with POST and got what? Where does `$command` come from?

Comment: @JonStirling With POST I got a Response, but not my token. Tried `result.json()` and got the following error message: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. `$command` comes from request: `$command = $_REQUEST["command"];`

Comment: Please update the question and show the _actual_ code of your PHP script then. Right now it does _not_ contain that assignment.

Comment: _"Unexpected token < in JSON"_ - most of the time that means you got an HTML response, such as an error document. Go check what the server actually responded with in the network panel.

Comment: json_encode will not put a < at the beginning, something else is adding output, find it and stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this case I'm getting this error message: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

GET requests generally pass data for the query using the query string (and jQuery's `getJSON` function will encode the data there).

First: Remove the body:

> ```
> body: JSON.stringify({command: "get_token"}),
> ```

Second: Remove the claim that the body contains JSON

> ```
> headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"},
> ```

Third: Encode the data in the query string:

```js
var url = new URL('php/data.php', location);
url.searchParams.append("command", "get_token");
var url_string = url.toString()
console.log(url_string);
fetch(url_string, {/* etc */})
```

Comment: OK, that sort of worked. Now I'm getting back a Promise that includes [[PromiseValue]] object which contains the token. But how do I access this Promise value?

Comment: [MDN tutorial on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) & [MDN tutorial on using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: `yourpromise.then(function (data) { console.log(data); });`

Comment: You probably want `this.myToken = result.token;` to be `return result.token`

Comment: That's exactly what I did: `fetch(url_string, {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "cors",
      cache: "no-cache",
      credentials: "same-origin",

    }).then(result => {
      console.log('fetch', result.json());
    })` But I'm getting the Promise object. If I try to use `result.token` I'm getting an error `Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Response'`

Comment: @Igal — I refer you, again, to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch — look at the very first block of code.

Comment: Yup, was already on it! :) Solved with `promise.then(result => {
      return result.json();
    }).then (resJson => {
      console.log(resJson.token);
    })`. Thank you very much!